# Angular eliminar una fila de la tabla usando MatDialog

Tags: angular

Tengo la siguiente tabla que carga perfectamente recibiendo datos `json` desde un **backend**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo el siguiente componente **"documento.component.ts"** que tiene un método para el botón **eliminar**   llamado **"abrirFormularioEliminacion(doc)"** que hace una llamada a un servicio llamado **"documento.service.ts"**

```
<form>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Código</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th colspan="2">Acción</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let doc of documentosArray; let i = index;">
            <td>{{doc.codigoDocumento}}</td>
            <td>{{doc.nombreDocumento}}</td>
            <td><button>Modificar</button></td>
            <td (click)="abrirFormularioEliminacion(doc)"><button>Eliminar</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</form>

constructor(
  public documentoService: DocumentoService
) { }

documentosArray: any;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.documentoService.obtenerListaDocumentos().subscribe(datos =>{
    this.documentosArray = datos;
  });
}

abrirFormularioEliminacion(doc: any){
  this.documentoService.abrirFormularioConfirmacion(doc.codigoDocumento);
}
```

**"documento.service.ts"** hace una llamada a otro componente que mostrará un **HTML** en un **Modal**

```
abrirFormularioConfirmacion(codigo: String){
  let matDialogRef: MatDialogRef<DocumentoModalComponent> = this.matDialog.open(DocumentoModalComponent, {
    width: '390px',
    disableClose: true
  });
  matDialogRef.componentInstance.codigoDocumento = codigo;
}
```

El componente que se mostrará como modal tiene el nombre de **"documento-modal.component.ts"** el cual solo tiene una variable que va ha recibir del código anterior y un método para cerrar el **Modal**.

```
<div>
    <div class="contenedor-contenido">
        ¿Estás seguro de querer eliminar el registro N° {{codigoDocumento}}?
    </div>
    <div>
        <button (click)="cerrarModal()">No</button><button>Si</button>
    </div>
</div>

constructor(
  public matdialogRef: MatDialogRef<DocumentoModalComponent>
) { }

codigoDocumento: String;

ngOnInit(): void {
}

cerrarModal(){
  this.matdialogRef.close();
}
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, pero quiero eliminar la fila de la tabla al presionar el botón "Si" del Modal. Se que debo usar la propiedad **splice** de javascript pero nose como hacer para que el componente del **documento-modal** encuentre la variable del componente **documento**, necesito una ayuda.

Comment: Que tipo de backend usas?

Comment: Estoy usando java como backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes suscribirte al evento `afterClosed` del dialog en el componente `documento.component.ts`. Para saber si ha clicado en `sí` tienes que emitir una respuesta para saber que hacer. Puedes usar la directiva `[mat-dialog-close]` en el componente modal.

```
<div>
    <div class="contenedor-contenido">
        ¿Estás seguro de querer eliminar el registro N° {{codigoDocumento}}?
    </div>
    <div>
        <button [mat-dialog-close]="false">No</button><button [mat-dialog-close]="true">Si</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Luego en el `documento.service.ts` puedes devolver la referencia del dialog abierto y suscribirte al evento que he comentado.

```
abrirFormularioConfirmacion(codigo: String){
  let matDialogRef: MatDialogRef<DocumentoModalComponent> = this.matDialog.open(DocumentoModalComponent, {
    width: '390px',
    disableClose: true
  });
  // para inyectar datos al dialog usa `MAT_DIALOG_DATA`
  matDialogRef.componentInstance.codigoDocumento = codigo;
  return matDialogRef;
}
```

En el componente `documento.component.ts` te suscribes.

```
abrirFormularioEliminacion(doc: any){
  this.documentoService.abrirFormularioConfirmacion(doc.codigoDocumento).afterClosed()
  .suscribe(result => {
     if (result) {
        // lo que quieras hacer
     }
  })
}
```

Te recomiendo mirar la api de `mat-dialog` https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples

Comment: Gracias por compartir tu respuesta me sirvió mucho y también por lo del `MAT_DIALOG_DATA`.

Comment: de nada. Encantando de haberte ayudado